# How to make widgets match parent but also have max width?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make 2 buttons in a Column, centred and match the parent.
But I also want to have a max width for this buttons in case of landscape mode / tablet.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            elevation: 4.0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            ),
            child: Text("A"),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("b"),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Now buttons take the whole screen. but I can't find a widget or a property to set size constraints

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your `Column` into a `ConstrainedBox` with a maxWidth, which you can then freely align with its parent using `Align`/`Center`

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300.0),
    child: Column(
       ...
    ),
  ),
)
```